# Impala default ports: were they changed?

Tags: impala

I deployed the latest version of Apache Impala from:

```
http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?action=download&filename=impala/3.3.0/apache-impala-3.3.0.tar.gz
```

and to see its used ports I used `netstat -- listen` (see below). Instead of 21000 I tried to use 31000 as the used ports by Impala are described at:

```
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/impala_ports.html
```

but could not connect from an impala-shell located at another computer (Tried 21000 but failed, too). Am I missing something? The impala daemon is running as if I do

```
root@bb9f4792e21d:/opt/Impala/bin# ps -ef | grep -i impalad
root     23067     1  0 15:31 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i impalad
```

I can see it is running.

```
root@bb9f4792e21d:/opt/Impala/bin# netstat --listen
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 *:11050                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:16010                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:7051                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:31020         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:31021         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:5070                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:31022         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:30130                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:10002                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:8051                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:16020         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:20500         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:16022         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:16023         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:31000                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:31001                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:30010                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:31002                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:9083                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:45979         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:16030                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:30911         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:6080                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:16032                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:16000         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:31200         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:9600                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:16033                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:31201         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:37857         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:31202         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:31010                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:31011                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:30020                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:31300                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:31012                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:6085          *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:2181                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:31301                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:42213         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:31302                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:45001        *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
udp        0      0 bb9f4792e21d:ntp        *:*                                
udp        0      0 localhost:ntp           *:*                                
udp        0      0 *:ntp                   *:*                                
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:39611        *:*                                
udp6       0      0 [::]:ntp                [::]:*                             
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     40977947 /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/socket.31001
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     40872735 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     40975999 /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/socket.31000
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     40977072 /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/socket.31002
root@bb9f4792e21d:/opt/Impala/bin#
```

Comment: It looks like you're running Impala (and a lot of other stuff) in a container. Did you expose the port to the outside world?

Comment: I did... Apaches's file runs a lot of things within just one Docker container. I feel something is needed to run for the port 21000 to appear in this list but I do not know what it is.

Comment: Exactly how did you expose the port?

Comment: Within my Dockerfile EXPOSE 21000 and similarly for the others

Comment: EXPOSE 21000 seems fine, but you have impalad listening on port 31000. That isn't going to work. You need to pick one or the other.

Comment: I also exposed 31000 and nothing.